# way to get rough user location without browser pop-up permission

Tags: html, geolocation

Is it possible to find the rough location of a user on the web without using the html5 geolocation stuff which brings up a box asking for the user's permission?  I have tried MaxMind but it seems pretty poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webserver (apache or somethigng like that) gets the users IP-adress when he sends a request to your server. There are some services in the web that can tell you the country and city of that address. Google for "location from ip address" to find those services. That is the best you can do without asking the user.

Everything more accurate MUST be explicitely allowed by the user himself for legal reasons. If a user finds out that you are tracking his position without having asked him, you can go to jail!!

Answer (score 0):

I've used [IPlocation.net](http://www.iplocation.net/) They provide a list of several providers and test them against your own IP to see if they get it correct.

I personally went with [IPinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/)